# Difference between Int and Uint8

Tags: swift, integer

What are the differences between the data types Int & UInt8 in Swift?

Looks like UInt8 is used for binary data, I need to convert UInt8 to Int. Is this possible?

Answer (score 9):

That U in UInt stands for unsigned int.

It is not just using for binary data. Uint is used for positive numbers only, like natural numbers.
I recommend you to get to know how negative numbers are understood from a computer.

Answer (score 5):

**Int8** is an Integer type which can store positive and negative values.

**UInt8** is an unsigned integer which can store only positive values.

You can easily convert **UInt8** to **Int8** but if you want to convert **Int8** to **UInt8** then make sure value should be positive.

Answer (score 3):

UInt8 is an 8bit store, while Int not hardly defined or defined by the compiler:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html

Int could be 32 or 64 bits

Answer (score 3):

> Updated for swift:

```
Operation                 Output Range                        Bytes per Element

uint8                     0 to 255                                   1 

Int          - 9223372036854775808 to 9223372036854775807          2 or 4
```

*If you want to find the max and min range of Int or UInt8:*

```
 let maxIntValue = Int.max
 let maxUInt8Value = UInt8.max

 let minIntValue = Int.min
 let minUInt8Value = UInt8.min
```

*If you want to convert UInt8 to Int, used below simple code:*

```
func convertToInt(unsigned: UInt) -> Int {
    let signed = (unsigned <= UInt(Int.max)) ?
        Int(unsigned) :
        Int(unsigned - UInt(Int.max) - 1) + Int.min

    return signed
}
```

Comment: Newbie here.  Thanks, Kiran, I needed that.  However, the entire range of UInt8 fits in an Int. Why can't/doesn't the compiler implicitly perform (and allow) the above convertToInt as "let myInt: Int = 1 as UInt8"?